# Msbuild target is not executed in incremental builds

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2022

I have a target, that compiles `scss` into `css` files in `Msbuild`.
The issue is that when I build the project the target is often not executed. As I found out, the problem is incremental builds - so `msbuild` decides to skip executing the task. How do I correctly configure Inputs/Outputs for incremental build to work properly with `Target`?

I have:

1. Input files, that are located in `\Styles\`. There can be a lot of files with folders there with extension `*.scss`
2. Output file is one `wwwroot\css\main.css`

My take on msbuild configuration:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <SCSSFiles Include="Styles\**\*.scss" />
    <CSSFile Include="wwwroot\css\main.css" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="CompileGlobalSass" BeforeTargets="Compile" Inputs="@(SCSSFiles)" Outputs="@(CSSFile)">
    <Message Text="++++++++++ Compiling global SCSS files" Importance="high" />
    <Exec Command="npm run sass -- Styles:wwwroot/css" />
</Target>
```

When I try to test this, I right click on my project and select `Build`. The first time I see my custom message. Then I change any `scss` file and select `Build` again - now the message is not displayed and my changes are not transpiled into `main.css`

Answer (score 1):

Do you want incremental builds will not ignore modified scss files in the Styles folder? If the scss file is modified, click Build, the CompileGlobalSass target will be executed?

You can try adding `<UpToDateCheckInput Include="Styles/**/*.scss"/>` in your project file.

Comment: People! This is the correct answer!