How to run custom MSBuild target if files changed
I want to achieve the following msbuild behaviour:

I run build on clear project and my custom target "OnFilesChange" fired.
I do not change anything and run build again, my custom target "OnFilesChange" is not fired and the whole build process skipped (nothing changed).
I change only tracked file from ./Plugins folder, only my custom target "OnFilesChange" fired, but not the whole build process.

Is it possible to do?
I have empty c# project with following structure:

The .csproj file contains following:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <SourceFilesFiles Include="Plugins\test.txt" />
    <DestinationFiles Include="$(OutputPath)\Plugins\test.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="OnFilesChange" Inputs="@(SourceFilesFiles)" Outputs="@(DestinationFiles)">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(SourceFilesFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(DestinationFiles)" />
  </Target>

</Project>

Here I tried to create a target (OnFilesChange) that on build should compare current ./Plugins/test.txt file with output ./bin/Debug/net8.0/Plugins/test.txt file. And if it was changed run my target "OnFilesChange". I tried it to save incremental build flow with all MSbuild optimisations but it is does not work properly.
P.S.
I did not find nice solution for this problem, but I found pretty nice workaround for this problem. Just include this in your .csproj file:
  <ItemGroup>
    <AdditionalFiles Include="path\to\you\files\**\*.*" Exclude="**\dist\**\*.*;**\node_modules\**\*.*;etc\files\to\exclude.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>

This workaround allows to track additional files and trigger normal build (instead of up-to-date).

Note: it is important that AdditionalFiles usually used for analyzers: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/analyzers/Using%20Additional%20Files.md


Some useful related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026355/how-to-avoid-that-visual-studio-incremental-build-does-not-run-when-files-outsid; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71964487/msbuild-target-is-not-executed-in-incremental-builds

Can you clarify what you mean by "I did not find nice solution for this problem, but I found pretty nice workaround for this problem."? Is "this problem" the same problem and you mean that you haven't solved your problem but you found a workaround for your problem?

@JonathanDodds I have solved my problem described at the very begining of the issue, but when we using AdditionalFiles it seems that whole build process triggered instead of granular target firing. Also as I noted AdditionalFiles used for analyzers, so it may potentially lead to some issues with analyzers (I have not noticed it yet).
So if you faced with similar problem, try this workaround.

I can write an answer that will explain how to do what you want.

@JonathanDodds Go ahead!
